# Changing default JENKINS_HOME directory on Ubuntu Install with apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am running an EC2 instance with an attached EBS of 100GB exclusively for the use of Jenkins Workspace (i.e. Jenkins_Home)

I mount the EBS at /mnt/jenkins and i set up the variable JENKINS_HOME to /mnt/jenkins before i install jenkins via apt-get

Still my jenkins defaults to /var/lib/jenkins/

How can i pass this information during / after setup before launch. I am not looking towards difficult management by moving the folder to the desired location and changing the config files.

What is the best practice regarding this.

Comment: Any reason you can't mount the volume to /var/lib/jenkins and symlink it to /mnt/jenkins if that's where you need it?

Comment: i could potentially do this way....  i can create the mountpoint to be /var/lib/jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup JENKINS_HOME by setting up the environment variable, either in profile, bashrc or /etc/profile.d/myvariables.sh for global use.

export JENKINS_HOME=/mnt/jenkins